# lsyncd: Is it possible to sync individual files from a list?

Tags: rsync, synchronization

I want to sync certain files from one linux system to another using lsyncd. The files are not confined to one directory, neither do I want all files from a directory.

Specifically I'm trying to make sure certain mail server files are kept in sync with a standby server. Here is a list:

`/etc/postfix/master.cf
/etc/postfix/main.cf
/etc/postfix/blocked_senders
/etc/postfix/relay_recipients
/etc/mail/spamassassin/local.cf`

Can I specify all these files in a single sync stanza via some kind of list or will I need to configure each individual file in separate sync stanzas?

Answer (score 5):

I suggest

```
--[[
The _extra= hack allows synchronization of individual files. Use one sync {}
stanza per source directory. Use additional --include= lines to handle multiple
files within a single source directory.
]]

sync {
  default.rsync,
  delay = 0,
  source = "/etc/postfix/",
  target = "standby.example.com:/etc/postfix/",
  rsync = {
    _extra = {
      "--include=master.cf",
      "--include=main.cf",
      "--include=blocked_senders",
      "--include=relay_recipients",
      "--exclude=*",
    }
  }
}

sync {
  default.rsync,
  delay = 0,
  source = "/etc/mail/spamassassin/",
  target = "standby.example.com:/etc/mail/spamassassin/",
  rsync = {
    _extra = {
      "--include=local.cf",
      "--exclude=*",
    }
  }
}
```

I think a sync {} stanza is needed for each source directory because lsyncd
detects changes efficiently via triggers established at the directory level.

Comment: Works fine, tried with "file.*", for 5 files with same name but different extension.

Answer (score 1):

Though this is an old one I would like put David's response into an "lsyncd" context. A sample configuration could look like this (tested and confirmed on one of my systems):

```
sync {
   default.rsyncssh,
   source = "/tmp",
   host = "gw2",
   targetdir = "/tmp",
   delete = false,
   rsync = { _extra = { "--files-from=/etc/lsyncd/files.list" } }
}
```

With the file /etc/lsyncd/files.list containing the files you want to sync with paths relative to "destination" (/tmp here).

Comment: That way seems strongly disapproved by the conceptor : 
https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd/issues/394

Comment: @tisc0: Just adding your solution here for informational purposes:
    _extra = {
       "--include=php.ini",
       "--exclude=*" }

Comment: Actually it's the solution of Marc just above :)

Answer (score 0):

Save them to a file *file_list*

```
rsync -a --files-from=file_list /source /dest
```

If only these 5 files, then I think you can also use -c (checksum check) and -z (compression) options.